# Cleanly suppress gcc's `final` suggestion warnings (`-Wsuggest-final-types` and `-Wsuggest-final-methods`)

Tags: c++, gcc, warnings, final

I like compiling my code using [`-Wsuggest-final-types`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html#index-Wsuggest-final-types) and [`-Wsuggest-final-methods`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html#index-Wsuggest-final-methods) in order to be warned about opportunities where the `final` keyword could be used to allow the compiler to optimize more aggressively.

Sometimes, though, the suggestions are incorrect - for example, I have a class `Base` with a `virtual ~Base()` destructor that is used polymorphically in another project, and gcc suggests me that `Base` could be marked as `final`.

Is there a way to "cleanly" tell the compiler that `Base` is used polymorphically and should not be marked as `final`?

The only way I can think of is using `#pragma` directives, but I find it makes the code cluttered and hard to read.

Ideally, I'm looking for a `non-final` keyword or attribute that can be prepended/appended to the class/method declaration.

Comment: I guess the intention is that you should use this occasionally to get a list of things to look into. And then turn it off.  Similar to sometimes compiling with `-Wall -Wextra` to get hints about things to check - most of which you can ignore.

Comment: If you are using a makefile, IDE, or separate build script, simply set up an alternate target (say "check").   For that build, set your compilation flags as you wish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I came up with a macro-based solution that I really don't like, but it solves the problem.

```
#define MARK_NONFINAL_CLASS(base)                              \
    namespace SOME_UNIQUE_NAME                                 \
    {                                                          \
        struct [[unused]] temp_marker final : base             \
        {                                                      \
        };                                                     \
    }

#define MARK_NONFINAL_METHOD(base, return_type, method)                  \
    namespace SOME_UNIQUE_NAME                                           \
    {                                                                    \
        struct [[unused]] temp_marker final : base                       \
        {                                                                \
            inline return_type [[unused]] method override {}             \
        };                                                               \
    }
```

Usage:

```
class Base
{
    virtual ~Base()
    {
    }

    virtual int a(float f)
    {
    }
    virtual void b(double)
    {
    }
};

MARK_NONFINAL_CLASS(Base)
MARK_NONFINAL_METHOD(Base, int, a(float))
MARK_NONFINAL_METHOD(Base, void, b(double))
```

Answer (score -1):

Allow me to make a suggestion (and this is how I solved these warnings problems).

The [GCC documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html) says:

> For example -Wsuggest-final-types is more effective with link-time optimization and some instances of other warnings may not be issued at all unless optimization is enabled.

So, to not show this warnings anymore, simply add the [link time optimization](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/LinkTimeOptimization) feature to your command line.

```
gcc -flto
```