# Is it possible to mark a class as non-final/derivable in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11

I like to use gcc compiler warning -Wsuggest-final-types, which gives valuable information about which classes could be marked as final.
Unfortunately, it also causes this warning for some base classes, which I explicitly created to be derived from (with virtual destructor and some other virtual methods, but no abstract methods). Is there a possibility to mark them in a way that the compiler does not emit this warning/suggestion (and also signal to other developers that they are meant to be derived from)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cleanly suppress gcc's \`final\` suggestion warnings (\`-Wsuggest-final-types\` and \`-Wsuggest-final-methods\`)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35311799/cleanly-suppress-gccs-final-suggestion-warnings-wsuggest-final-types-and)

Comment: Does making the destructor pure virtual fix your problem? That definitely leads to an abstract class, I don't know if that's all `-Wsuggest-final-types` cares about. (You can/should still implement it, but it can be declared as pure virtual). A [mcve] would not hurt ;)

Comment: @Quentin: you are correct, this is a duplicate of the question, but I hope to get a better answer than the accepted one at the duplicate question. What should I do? Keep this question open as a "different" one?

Comment: @MaxLanghof: If I make the destructor pure virtual (still with implementation of the destructor), I cannot use the base class itself anymore, e.g. as a return type, because it is now an abstract type.

Comment: Not sure, but I won't bite you if you keep this question open ;)

Comment: Also, we wouldn't mind having an example that demonstrates the warning to work from, I haven't been able to trigger it so far...

Comment: @Quentin: I am still trying to get a minimal example to reproduce the warning outside of my huge project...